# Newline on win32 gui textbox when using SetWindowText

Tags: c++, windows

I create a textbox on a win32 gui app. Later on I'm trying to set a text to it but newline "\n" isn't working when using `SetWindowText`

```
g_ButtonManager.hWndThirtyText = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""),
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE,
       10, 95, //x,y
       200, 60, //width, height
       hWnd, (HMENU)IDM_THIRTYTEXT, NULL, NULL);
```

Even though I:

```
SetWindowTextA(g_ButtonManager.hWndThirtyText, "Hello\nThere");
```

It displays `HelloThere` in the same line.

[image]

---Edit

Even with `| ES_WANTRETURN`

```
g_ButtonManager.hWndThirtyText = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("Hello\nMy\nFriend"),
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN,,
       10, 95, //x,y
       200, 60, //width, height
       hWnd, (HMENU)IDM_THIRTYTEXT, NULL, NULL);
```

Will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured it.

`\r\n` is required for a newline.

Comment: If someone could explain why, though

Comment: With the printer "\r" is a carriage return(CR), "\n" is a line feed(LF)

Comment: @snoopy on Windows, `\r\n` is the standard line break in text, files, etc. Multi-line Edit controls enforce that.